# How can I use column number for dplyr::count()?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
```

This is OK.

```
count(iris, Species) 
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     Species     n
      <fctr> <int>
1     setosa    50
2 versicolor    50
3  virginica    50
> names(iris)[5]
[1] "Species"
```

This does not work. Why?
How can I use column number for dplyr::count() ?

```
> count(iris, one_of(names(iris)[5])) 
    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  wrong result size (0), expected 150 or 1
In addition: Warning message:
In one_of(names(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4,  :
  Unknown variables: `Species`
```

Comment: try using the `count_` function.  Such as: count_(iris, names(iris)[2])

Answer (score 0):

`count(iris, iris[,5])` should produce the same result with yours.
Not sure about `one_of`, but if you delete that and add a `,`in `[5]`it should produce the result without error.